When solution of a differential equation is of bounded variation?
Consider the differential equation
$$ \frac{dx}{dt} = f(t,x),~~0 \le t \le 1, a \le x \le b$$ with initial condition $x(0)=x_{0}$. We know that if the function $f$ is Lipschitz continuous w.r.t. $x$, then there will exist unique solution to given initial value problem on some rectangle. But is it possible to impose any condition on function $f$ such that the solution is of bounded variation?

If $f$ is merely continuous, every solution $x$ is continuously differentiable. Are you asking about weaker conditions on $f$...?

You also might want to take a look at Filippov solutions
